# After rebuild of TFS 2013 services pack 4 Test controller will not configure

Tags: testing, tfs, controllers

After I rebuild TFS from a disk crash, I update to service pack four and and created new Project collections. While setting up the test controller, I cant get it to configure because somewhere it is pulling the old project collection name when it try's to perform the Register test controller process.

The error message in the event log is below;

Service cannot be started. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Exceptions.EqtException: The Controller service could not be started. TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server http://myserver:8080/tfs/***modelsyscollection***.
Technical information (for administrator):
  Page not found.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerServiceBase.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

The project collection name should be **modelsysllc**. I'm not sure where the configuration tool is pulling this old name from.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the test controller being setup on a new machine or on the same machine?

That error message is coming from the test controller, so I expect it is an issue on the machine running the test controller (perhaps something in the registry).